# Possible gSheets ArrayFormula display bug

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I can almost always find an answer here for a problem, but not this time so I'm asking the community.

I'm having a problem with ArrayFormula not displaying the text in the True branch of an IF when the condition evaluates to True.  Instead it displays the text associated with the False branch.

The array formulas are all on row 4.  I thought it might be caused by one of them referencing row 5 instead of row 4 and showing the result from the next row but that isn't it.

I thought it might be a corrupted sheet but after recreating in a new sheet the problem was still present.

It is easier to show than to explain so I've provided the gsheet and a short screencast below.  A link to the screencast is also in A1 in the gsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H7W__hM2L89faxIOZ23WgboXHgaWe0wYT20aWVr_vD8/edit?usp=sharing

https://www.loom.com/share/a867787fdc6044a3840125e288d4cb8c?from_recorder=1

Thanks much for taking a look...

Answer (score 1):

`AND` formula is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA`

use multiplication:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(D4:D="",,
 IF(D4:D<0, "No Profit",
 IF(H4:H/(G4:G+1)*D4:D<D1,
 IF((C4:C>C1)*(E4:E>(C1*3-1)), "Low Profit"&
 TEXT(H4:H/(G4:G+1)*D4:D, "$00"), "Low Price"), H4:H/(G4:G+1)*D4:D))))
```

also note that anchoring `$` in "true" `AF` is kinda pointless